# Как убрать вертикальную полосу в контекстном меню PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, pyqt6, contextmenu

Я пытался убрать полосу за счёт `.setIconVisibleInMenu(False)`. 
Я думаю, что это можно убрать, т.к. в *tkinter* аналогичное контекстное меню выглядит так:

[image: tkinter]

*PyQt*:

[image: PyQt]

---

Код:

```
import sys
from tkinter import Menu, Tk
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QMenu
)


class PyQt(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ПКМ - PyQt")

    def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
        context = QMenu(self)
        context.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        context.addAction("<- This")
        context.exec(self.mapToGlobal(e.pos()))


class Tkinter(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("ПКМ - Tkinter")
        self.menu = Menu(tearoff=1000)
        self.menu.add_command(label='<- This')
        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.pkm)

    def pkm(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = PyQt()
    p.show()
    t = Tkinter()
    t.mainloop()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и расскажите лучше что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick Исправлено

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys

#from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
# -> v^v^v^ <----------------------------
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QAction, QLabel, 
    QWidget, QMainWindow, 
    QMenu
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont


class Window(QMainWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
                
        self._createActions()
        
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("ПКМ - PyQt")
        self.centralWidget = QLabel("Hello, World", font=QFont("Calibri", 20))
        self.centralWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  
        
        self.context = QMenu()
        self.context.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)        
        self.context.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.context.setStyleSheet("""
            QMenu{
                  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                  border-radius: 10px;
                  border: 2px solid red;
            }
            QMenu::item {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    padding:3px 10px;
                    margin:5px 5px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QMenu::item:selected { background-color: gray; color: #fff;}
        """)

        newAct = self.context.addAction(self.newAction)
        openAct = self.context.addAction(self.openAction)
        self.context.addSeparator()
        quitAct = self.context.addAction(self.exitAction)  

        QApplication.instance().focusObjectChanged.connect(self.focusChanged)    
        self._connectActions()

    def focusChanged(self, obj):
        if not obj or obj.window() == self.window():
            self.context.hide()        

    def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
        self.context.hide()
        self.context.exec(self.mapToGlobal(e.pos()))
        
    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("&New")
        self.openAction = QAction("<- This...", self)
        self.exitAction = QAction("&Quit", self) 
        
    def _connectActions(self):
        self.newAction.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)  
        
    def newFile(self):
        self.centralWidget.setText("<b>File > <i style='color: red'>New...</i></b> clicked")
        self.context.hide()

    def openFile(self):
        self.centralWidget.setText("<b>File > <i style='color: red'>&lt;- This...</i></b> clicked")
        self.context.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Window()
    p.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это работает, но выглядит как костыль. Можно ли изменить только один параметр в `StyleSheet`, чтобы край слева пропал, а остальное зависело от системы?

Comment: @Sonter на счет костыля, это вы сами придумали или вам кто-то подсказал?

Comment: @s-nick первое. Данный способ позволяет полностью кастомизировать QMenu, что в данном случае не нужно. Желательно оставить системный вариант QMenu, убрав оттуда только отступ слева и белую полосу (обводку)